# Travelling to Windsor from Michigan (expired passport)

Tags: canada, road-trips

Travelling to Windsor from Grand Rapids MI next week but my passport expired 8 months ago...
I have no criminal record and will have proof of citizenship and my ID. Will I be able to go through the border?

Comment: What is your country of citizenship? What other proof and ID will you carry?

Answer (score 2):

The return back from Canada to the US will likely be the most time-consuming part of the journey

The US require a [WHTI-compliant travel document](https://www.usa.gov/enter-us)

> American citizens entering the U.S. must show a valid passport, U.S. passport card, a Trusted Traveler Program card (NEXUS, SENTRI, Global Entry or FAST), or an enhanced driver’s license. If you have any questions, contact your carrier to find out if they require a specific document

Now, a US citizen can't be [denied entry](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/16655/36084) back to the US, so what will likely happen is that you will be held in secondary inspection while they check your citizenship, and you will also get a speech about the fact that you needed a valid travel document

Answer (score 0):

According to the Canada Border Services Agency, US citizens need proof of citizenship to enter Canada, such as:

> - Passport
> - Birth Certificate
> - Certificate of Citizenship or Naturalization
> - U.S. Permanent Resident Card
> - Certificate of Indian Status along with photo identification.
> - NEXUS card

[Source](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ivc-rnc-eng.html)

As you say you've got ID and proof of citizenship you should be fine crossing the land border into Canada.

Comment: This is correct, I guess, but assuming they want to get back into the US too, they will need [a WHTI-compliant travel document](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative).

Comment: @mlc The US will allow citizens to enter by providing proof of US citizenship

Comment: @Midavalo After hours in secondary and a long speech from CBP, not a fun thing

Comment: Canada is significantly less restrictive on land crossings (ID-wise) for U.S. citizens than the other way around. Technically CBSA could (and does) even accept an oral declaration of citizenship (with other government ID); but of course you have to right to that and cannot rely on the good mood of the officer on the day.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I know many people who do this regularly (although I don't advise it) and they never have any issues or long speeches from CBP.  Birth certificate and/or driver license (not EDL)  and they're through.  I have crossed the border several times with them, and it doesn't seem to take any longer than if they had a passport.

Answer (score -1):

As a US citizen, you need:

"Entry into Canada: Canadian law requires that all persons entering Canada carry proof of citizenship and identity. A **valid U.S. passport**, **passport card**, or **NEXUS card** satisfies these requirements for U.S. citizens."

From : [https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Canada.html#:~:text=Entry%20into%20Canada%3A%20Canadian%20law,need%20proof%20of%20U.S.%20citizenship](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Canada.html#:%7E:text=Entry%20into%20Canada%3A%20Canadian%20law,need%20proof%20of%20U.S.%20citizenship).